# acpi not running action

Tags: brightness, acpi

I have a scripts to control display brightness:

`/etc/acpi/actions/bl_down.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
echo $(($(/usr/bin/cat $bl_device)-10)) | sudo /usr/bin/tee $bl_device
```

Running it as `./bl_down.sh` works as expected.

So I tried to bind it to my keyboard like so:

`/etc/acpi/events/bl_down`:

```
event=video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000 K
action=/etc/acpi/actions/bl_down.sh
```

However, this doesn't do anything except print the following in `journalctl`:

```
 May 20 13:53:51 mowgli root[32154]: ACPI group/action undefined: video/brightnessdown / BRTDN
```

Any ideas?

Volume UP and DOWN outputs:

`ACPI group/action undefined: button/volumedown / VOLDN`

However, it works just fine.

Comment: Maybe you need to start the `systemctl start apcid.service` to register those events. Try to run `acpi_listen` and push the buttons to see what they fire.

Comment: @eckes acpid is running fine. ```/etc/acpi/actions                                                              
▶ acpi_listen
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

update your file  /etc/acpi/events/bl_down   and quote the definition

```
event="video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000 K "
```

shell variables assignments to a string must have the entire string quoted

Comment: Didn't change anything

Comment: what does  `journalctl -xe  `  say

Comment: Same thing as in OP: `ACPI group/action undefined: video/brightnessup / BRTUP`

Comment: your original question concerned brightnessdown ... yet now error says brightnessup ... are both quoted now ?

Comment: I binding both of them. They have the same issue. I just copied the wrong one.